# Python, Как отсортировать список на основе другого списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, сортировка

```
box_b = [7, 3, 9, 5]
box_a = [apple, banana, cherry, lemon]
```

Суть в том, что после сортировки `box_b` мне нужен `box_a` отсортированный таким же образом.

```
# after sorting box_b and some algorithm*

box_b = [3, 5, 7, 9]
box_a = [banana, lemon, apple, cherry]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
box_b = [7, 3, 9, 5]
box_a = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'lemon']

new_b, new_a = zip(*[(b, a) for b, a in sorted(zip(box_b, box_a))])

print(new_b)
(3, 5, 7, 9)

print(new_a)
('banana', 'lemon', 'apple', 'cherry')
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё можно сделать arg_sort — получить список индексов, по которым нужно пройти, чтобы получить отсортированный список. Это удобно, если данные тяжёлые, а вам нужна только итерация по отсортированным данным.

```
box_b = [7, 3, 9, 5]
box_a = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'lemon']

arg_sort = sorted(range(len(box_b)), key=lambda i: box_b[i])
print([box_b[i] for i in arg_sort])
print([box_a[i] for i in arg_sort])
# [3, 5, 7, 9]
# ['banana', 'lemon', 'apple', 'cherry']
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле решение `S. Nick` можно записать ещё короче, одна операция там лишняя:

```
new_b, new_a = zip(*sorted(zip(box_b, box_a)))
```